# ios unity game crashed at startup (most likely because of ads) I have the symbolicated backtrace

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, crash

```
 <pre><code>OS Version:          iPhone OS 17.0 (21A329)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    3.06.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Reason: -[%s %s]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1031ea360
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1ae6725e0 __exceptionPreprocess + 164 (NSException.m:249)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1a69a3c00 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:356)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1ae702eec -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 344 (NSObject.m:161)
3   UIKitCore                       0x1b15b2584 -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 260 (UIResponder.m:703)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1ae5b7554 ___forwarding___ + 968 (NSForwarding.m:3654)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x1ae6f8860 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96 (:-1)
6   UnityFramework                  0x10794b0e8 __57-[UADSBannerLoadModuleDelegateWrapper bannerViewDidShow:]_block_invoke (in UnityFramework) + 92 + 3813608
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x1b64b16a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1530)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x1b64b3300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:561)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x1b64c1998 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 984 (queue.c:7813)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x1b64c15b0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44 (queue.c:7973)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x1ae5bc9bc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1780)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x1ae5b96c8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1996 (CFRunLoop.c:3149)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x1ae5b8e18 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608 (CFRunLoop.c:3420)
14  GraphicsServices                0x1f10755ec GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2196)
15  UIKitCore                       0x1b09c7350 -[UIApplication _run] + 888 (UIApplication.m:3690)
16  UIKitCore                       0x1b09c698c UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIApplication.m:5275)
17  UnityFramework                  0x1075bdf90 -[UnityFramework runUIApplicationMainWithArgc:argv:] (in UnityFramework) (main.mm:96) + 90000
18  EndlessFall                     0x102afbcac main (in EndlessFall) (main.mm:28) + 31916
19  dyld                            0x1d0d9bd44 start + 2104 (dyldMain.cpp:1269)

Kernel Triage:
VM - (arg = 0x3) mach_vm_allocate_kernel failed within call to vm_map_enter
VM - (arg = 0x3) mach_vm_allocate_kernel failed within call to vm_map_enter
VM - (arg = 0x3) mach_vm_allocate_kernel failed within call to vm_map_enter
VM - (arg = 0x3) mach_vm_allocate_kernel failed within call to vm_map_enter
VM - (arg = 0x3) mach_vm_allocate_kernel failed within call to vm_map_enter
```

that's the backtrace

I have tried updating the ads, and updating the skadnetwork ids.
I am not familiar with apple's style for codes and i have created the ios game on windows.
I do not know what am I looking at for the backtrace and require assistance.
it is a symbolicated crash log.

i suspected it's the unity ads crashing the game on start from advertisement.initialize()
but i want to see what you guys say occurs from this backtrace.

thank you so much for your time and patience!